# OneDrive how to get access tokens for iOS app and server-side app simultaneously

Tags: ios, authentication, server-side, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

The app I am working on shows the content of OneDrive on the mobile device and perform some work with that content on the server when the user is offline. There is quite clear way how to get the token to get access to OneDrive from the iOS app. But I spent a lot of time and couldn't figure out a way how to get the token for the server simultaneously with the mobile one. (We can do it with Google Drive, for example, when we get the token for mobile app and the auth code for the server-side app simultaneously). Is there a way to do it with OneDrive and how it could be done?